# Difference between two time intervals in series

Tags: python, time

Lets say that i have a duration of time e.g., 10 minutes . 
I have the start time and end time defined .

e.g., start time is 10 A.M and end time is 2 P.M .

I need the time intervals of

```
10-10.10 , 10.10 - 10.20 , .. , 10.50-11 etc.,
```

stored in the database .

Here is what i have in mind.

```
from datetime import datetime
time1 = '10:00'
time2 = '10.10' 
format = '%H:%M'
obj1 = datetime.strptime(time1, format) - datetime.strptime(time2, format)
```

This is okay for two known intervals . What bout two unknown intervals and to store them in the database?

How can i solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store duration, start and end times in the database. You can always generate time intervals later:

```
def time_range(start, end, duration):
    dt = start
    while dt < end: #note: `end` is not included in the range
        yield dt
        dt += duration
```

#### Example

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# dummy data
duration = timedelta(minutes=10)
start = datetime.utcnow()
end = start + timedelta(hours=16)

# use list instead of tee(), islice() for simplicity 
lst = [dt.strftime('%H:%M') for dt in time_range(start, end, duration)] 
for interval in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
    print "%s-%s," % interval,
print
```

Comment: Great answer . Just want one thing clarified . What does the yield statement do?

Comment: @Pavan: [The Python yield keyword explained](http://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/4279)